# Scheduling RDS only to run when a scheduled Fargate task is running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs

I have a Fargate task that runs regularly once a day. Other than that, there is no need for the database to be up and running. Any way to make it so that the Fargate task triggers the start and stop of the RDS database instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the option could be to switch to Serverless DB i.e. [AWS Aurora serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/)

> Amazon Aurora Serverless is an on-demand, auto-scaling configuration
>   for Amazon Aurora (MySQL-compatible and PostgreSQL-compatible
>   editions), where the database will automatically start up, shut down,
>   and scale capacity up or down based on your application's needs. It
>   enables you to run your database in the cloud without managing any
>   database instances. It's a simple, cost-effective option for
>   infrequent, intermittent, or unpredictable workloads.

Another option to setup a lambda that you can trigger when you need it. This blog provides all the details for that

https://dzone.com/articles/create-an-aws-lambda-function-to-stop-and-start-an

Answer (score 1):

I think I'll go the way of this python script:

```
import json
import time
import subprocess


def run_command(command):
    command_list = command.split(' ')
    result = subprocess.run(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
    output = json.loads(result.stdout)
    return result, output


def db_status(db_name):
    desc_cmd = f'python -m awscli rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier {db_name}'
    _, res = run_command(desc_cmd)
    return res['DBInstances'][0]['DBInstanceStatus']


def stop_db(db_name, block=True):
    stop_cmd = f"python -m awscli rds stop-db-instance --db-instance-identifier {db_name}"
    run_command(stop_cmd)
    if block:
        while db_status(db_name) != 'stopped':
            time.sleep(2)


def start_db(db_name, block=True):
    start_cmd = f"python -m awscli rds start-db-instance --db-instance-identifier {db_name}"
    run_command(start_cmd)
    if block:
        while db_status(db_name) != 'available':
            time.sleep(2)
```

And simply call `start_db` and `stop_db` before and after my Fargate task.